# The Data Parameters values of .ajax() method is not passed to the C# function in asp.net core 2.0

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I am doing a very simply **ajax() method** call in **asp.net core 2.0**. It is just calling a controller function from view. It also passes value using the **data** parameter.

The C# function is getting called but the **controller function parameter** is not **receiving the value**.

The code:

```
var idChecked = 5;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/BlogCategory/UpdateBulkStatus",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: '{"idChecked":"' + idChecked + '"}',
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (msg) {

    },
    error: function (req, status, error) {

    }
});
```

Controller function

```
public string UpdateBulkStatus(string idChecked)
{
  return "abc";
}
```

[image]

The **idChecked** variable is null always.

What is wrong? The same code works on MVC 5 but not on core?

Comment: Just use `data: { idChecked: idChecked },` and delete the `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` And since you are passing a `int`, your parameter should be `int`, not `string`.

Comment: Thank you @StephenMuecke. I changed the data data: { idChecked: idChecked } and removed the contentType , like you said. It worked now. It was working previously on MVC 5 but on core 2.0 it stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are passing is an object not a string and the model binder is "guessing" where it is coming from. Mark the location of the parameter to bind using the attribute and match the data exactly.

```
public string UpdateBulkStatus([FromBody]BulkStatus bulkStatus)
{
   return bulkStatus.idChecked;
}

public class BulkStatus
{
     public string idChecked {get;set;}
}
```